# How server know request is not from browser

Tags: web-crawler

- Recently, i have some crawling tasks. 
  I saw a lot of website (such as Amazon ) can know my api calling is not from Browser and response some message like "Bot detected" or return capcha. Immediately i call api or url from browser, and it's still work.
- I did clone the request SAME LIKE browser call by copy as curl (user agent , cookie , .. all same).
- How they know my request did not come from browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh... in that case, you'll want to make your User-Agent something less obvious and standard. That will trick *some* websites. For instance, Firefox uses: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0

The smarter ones or those that use Cloudflare will recognize you to be a fake. So, you'll want to use something like UIPath or Selenium to mimic a human. There really is no other way to trick the big boys like Amazon. You can use their API to get the data you are after most likely, but it has limits.

*NB: I left my previous answer simply because I'm sure people will google this and want to know how to restrict certain bots. This answers the OPs question more directly.

Comment: I did clone all same. I see they using Google recapcha to get a token to access their API. I decide to use Puppeteer to crawl as human

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways of significantly reducing the number of bots crawling your site:

1. [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com) ~ This free service will act as a barrier between the website and user, meaning it will only allow legitimate users to access your website.
2. Put a robots.txt file in your root directory. This provides instructions to bots. This will block many bots, but not the ones masquerading as a real user (which is why Cloudflare is so great because it does block almost all of the bad bots. However, robots.txt is usually sufficient. For instance, is you wanted to block all bots from a specific directory you would use:

   User-agent: *

   Disallow: /

This will block *all* bots, including legitimate bots like Google. You usually don't want to do this, except in your site's admin directory or a few other directories.

The following would block Googlebot completely:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /
```

Given the previous example, you need to analyze your Google Analytics data and look for suspicious User-agents and replace Googlebot from above with the name of the agents.

Comment: Thank you . But i mean , i want to crawl those websites.

Comment: @ThieuAnh Please see my second answer. I'm pretty sure that will answer your question. Let me know if you have any questions. Most people use Selenium, but there is a learning curve. UIPath would be easier if you aren't a programmer, but will be using a lot more system resources literally clicking around like a human. I've seen few captcha solvers for Selenium on the dark web too. Could also hire a freelancer for that (not me... I hate that stuff, bores the heck out of me). G'luck.

Comment: Crawl by robot on UI is quite slow . I try to access API

Comment: @Thieu, Indeed it is. Although Selenium is able to get around that, but it can be a pain in the butt if you haven't worked with it before. Unfortunately for those looking to scrape data, they don't make it easy... but they do so for good reason. Best of luck w/ it.

Comment: robots.txt does not block bots that ignore the file altogether, only "nice" bots that actually try to obey a website's rules

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of tech to prevent crawling from sites.
If you want to crawl that site, you should make your crawler like a person.

1) set sleep time randomly between requests

2) set random user-agent at each request

3) you can do crawl by making proxies farm

there are also different things to crawl that site by analyzing http traffic.

Comment: I did clone all same. I see they using Google recapcha V3 to get a token to access their API. I decide to use Puppeteer to crawl as human